# How to send Screenshot to STDOUT

Tags: bash, command-line

I currently extract text from image using:

```
import png:- | convert png:- -units PixelsPerInch -resample 300 -sharpen 12x6.0 png:- | tesseract -l eng stdin stdout | xsel -ib
```

However, `import png:-` command to take screenshot is not working well for me. It somehow do not quite suit Linux Mint.

[image]

Is there any other command which I can use to directly send screenshot to STDOUT for further processing.

Comment: I'll assume this is Xorg, not wayland, right?

Comment: yes this is xorg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having similar issues with `scrot`. In that case I added a sleep and it was fine! Worked fine for me, but I'm not on Linux Mint.

```bsh
{ import png:-; sleep 0.1 ;} | convert png:- -units PixelsPerInch -resample 300 -sharpen 12x6.0 png:- | tesseract -l eng stdin stdout | xsel -ib
```

Also, you could try out scrot with something like:

```bsh
scrot -s aoeu.png -e 'tesseract -l eng $f stdout | xsel -ib; rm -f $f'
```

---

A version incorporating input in comments and the answer from [J. Cravens](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/690034/176618)

```bsh
scrot -s -f -q 100 --silent - |
    convert - -units PixelsPerInch -resample 300 -sharpen 12x6.0 - |
    tesseract -l eng stdin stdout |
    xsel -ib
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The command that is working for me is: `scrot -s -f -e 'convert $f -units PixelsPerInch -resample 300 -sharpen 12x6.0 png:- | tesseract -l eng stdin stdout | xsel -ib; rm -f $f'`. `-f` freeze the screen and the problem goes away. However, if there any way to send file as `png` directly to stdout so that i do not have to write to the disk.

Comment: The solution I am currently using is : `maim -s | convert - -units PixelsPerInch -resample 300 -sharpen 12x6.0 - | tesseract -l eng stdin stdout | xsel -ib`

Comment: Did you test `scrot -` in your pc. The `-` does not work in my machine. It does not send anything to stdout.

Comment: Yes! Tested with scrot version `1.7`.

Comment: Mine is 1.2 probably that is why it is not working.

Comment: The ability to use `-` to save to stdout was added in 1.7, according to https://github.com/resurrecting-open-source-projects/scrot/commit/da22a83ac9d5116ca4e7bd008678dfd6087bf0a8#diff-91c5b46dc84a94604a4e4d0caed9bf85590a2eddbb12d2e8dc80badf324a9dfbR18

Answer (score 1):

You can use scrot with - for standard output, but it will default save a png file.  Just add:

`scrot -q 100 --silent - |`

Should be exactly what it was looking for.

UPDATE: To do this with versions below 1.7, as it does not accept - as stdout, will be a bit more tricky. Here's a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a temp working directory
temp_file="$HOME/screenshot_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S").png"

# Take a screenshot to the temp file
scrot -zfq 100 --silent "$temp_file"

# Copy the image file to the clipboard using xclip
xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i "$temp_file"

echo -e "\nScreenshot saved to:\n"$temp_file"\n"

exit 0
```

With `xclip`, it's ready to paste/output.  Piping to `xsel` etc. should work the same.

Save it to `screenshot.sh`
Then, `chmod +x screenshot.sh`
Finally, run `./screenshot.sh`

**Tip:** Use an alias to run scripts in a single command.
[How To Create BASH Aliases](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/)

```
alias sshot='bash -c "/path/to/script/screenshot.sh"'
```

Now you can take a screenshot by simply typing: `sshot`

Comment: `scrot -s -f` works for me, but not understanding how to send this image to stdout.

Comment: That is what the - before the | indicates is to stdout, easy as that.  The -q is quality and default was 75 and given you are extracting text, I figured best quality possible.  The --silent part is just in case, avoid problems before they happen.

Comment: I should probably incorporate your answer in mine!

Comment: Great work!  Nice and tidy.  

Comment: using `-` for standard output works in current (v1.7) but doesn't work with earlier versions (v1.4) packaged with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or earlier.

Comment: Version 1.5 also doesn't seem to work - it just outputs a png file called `-`.

Comment: @mwfearnley Added a script to help with versions below 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

KDE's `spectacle` screenshot tool lets you output to stdout, but only using `/dev/stdout` instead of `-`:

`spectacle --background --fullscreen --output /dev/stdout`

or, with short options: `spectacle -bfo /dev/stdout`